# materialize css responsive navbar not working on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design, materialize, responsive

I have the following code

```
<nav class="blue">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
</nav>
```

I only have the centred logo in my code. However when I view this code on mobile devices, the navbar becomes very small in height. Why is the responsive classes not working in this case?

> Note that I am not concerned with collapsing navbar elements to a sidenav. Right now the navbar itself looks very small (in height) on a mobile devices, which makes me think that somewhere some responsive stuff is missing.

As an example of my problem I'm attaching this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooJrpm?editors=1000). Try rendering it in different resolutions by resizing horizontally, the navbar will become shorter in height on smaller devices.

Edit 1: If you look at the screenshot below, it's not only that the navbar isn't responsive, but the entire content on the page is not being responsive.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I was missing a `meta viewport` tag on my page.

Basically just adding this made it work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This allowed the existing media queries (ones provided by materializecss itself) to work properly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Usually adding this meta tag to your `<head>` will solve the issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but I had a problem, where although I added this meta tag, it seemed like it doesn't obey it. The nav bar was still much too wide.

The reason was that there was an element on the page, that was wider than 100% width and although it had overflow: hidden, this width still bent the page width.

I changed that element and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px)
materialize.css:4477
nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.sidenav-trigger, nav a.sidenav-trigger i {
    height: 64px;
}
```

This is a rule inside the materialize.css file. It gets applied for widths of 601px or higher.

```
nav {
    height: 56px;
}
```

This is the default, for 600px or less. Maybe try

```
nav {
    height: 64px;
}
```

to keep things consistent?

Comment: see my updated question. Its not that only the navbar is not being responsive, but other elements too are not rendering as responsive elements.